# How to make images smaller in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-illustrator

I'm making a game slot and created images in illustrator but when I transferred them to javascript they are really big. Is there anyway to make them small in javascript or do I have to create them again and make them smaller?

Here is my code:

```
 window.onload = function() {


        //global variables
        var credit=0;
        var betAmount=0;
        var THREE_DIAMONDS="";
        var TWO_DIAMONDS="";
        var ONE_DIAMOND="";
        var SAME_BOTH="";
        var SAME_COLOR="";
        var SAME_SHAPE="";


        var redSquare={shape:"square", color:"red", width:100, height:100, image:"images/apple.png"};
        var blueCircle={shape:"circle", color:"blue", width:100, height:100,image:"images/apple2.png"};
        var blueSquare={shape:"square", color:"blue", width:100, height:100,image:"images/apple3.png"};
        var blueTriangle={shape:"triangle", color:"blue", width:100, height:100,image:"images/cherry.png"};
        var greenCircle={shape:"circle", color:"green",width:100, height:100, image:"images/cherry2.png"};
        var greenSquare={shape:"square", color:"green", width:100, height:100,image:"images/cherry3.png"};
        var greenTriangle={shape:"triangle", color:"green", width:100, height:100,image:"images/watermelon.png"};
        var redCircle={shape:"circle", color:"red", width:100, height:100,image:"images/watermelon2.png"};
        var redTriangle={shape:"triangle", color:"red", width:100, height:100,image:"images/watermelon3.png"};
        var yellowDiamond={shape:"diamond", color:"yellow", width:100, height:100,image:"images/passion.png"};
        var blackSquare={shape:"square", color:"black", width:100, height:100,image:"images/blackSquare.png" };

        var slotShapes= [blackSquare, redSquare, redTriangle, redCircle, greenSquare, greenTriangle, greenCircle, blueSquare, blueTriangle, blueCircle, yellowDiamond]


        //attaches event to the drop down!

        document.getElementById("theList").onchange = function() {

            credit = parseInt(document.getElementById("theList").value);

            document.getElementById("credits").value= credit;  

            document.getElementById("theList").disabled = true;

            document.getElementById("theList").value = 0;

            document.getElementById("clickMe").disabled = false;

            document.getElementById("img1").src = slotShapes[Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1].image;
            document.getElementById("img2").src = slotShapes[Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1].image;
            document.getElementById("img3").src = slotShapes[Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1].image;

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Good luck!!!";


        }

        var threePics=[];

        document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function() {

            if (document.getElementById("bet1").checked === true){
                betAmount="1";
            } else if (document.getElementById("bet2").checked === true){
                betAmount="2";
            } else if (document.getElementById("bet3").checked === true){
                betAmount="3";
            }

            credit = credit - betAmount;

            document.getElementById("credits").value= credit;

            for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*19)+1;

                switch (random)
                {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[1].image; 
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[1];
                        break;
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[2].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[2];
                        break;
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[3].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[3];
                        break;
                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[4].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[4];
                        break;
                    case 9:
                    case 10:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[5].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[5];
                        break;
                    case 11:
                    case 12:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[6].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[6];
                        break;
                    case 13:
                    case 14:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[7].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[7];
                        break;
                    case 15:
                    case 16:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[8].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[8];
                        break;
                    case 17:
                    case 18:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[9].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[9];
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).src = slotShapes[10].image;
                        threePics[i]= slotShapes[10];
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (threePics[0].color === "yellow" && threePics[1].color === "yellow" && threePics[2].color === "yellow"){

                //jackpot


                } else if (threePics[0].color === "yellow" && threePics[1] === "yellow" ||
                           threePics[0].color === "yellow" && threePics[2] === "yellow" ||
                           threePics[1].color === "yellow" && threePics[2] === "yellow") {

                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "NICE!!! Two diamonds pay " + (TWO_DIAMONDS * betAmount) + " on a bet of " + betAmount;

                } else if (threePics[0].color === "yellow" || threePics[1].color === "yellow" || threePics[2].color === "yellow") {
                    credit = credit + (ONE_DIAMOND * betAmount);

                } else if (threePics[0].shape === threePics[1].shape && threePics[0].shape === threePics[2].shape &&
                           threePics[0].color === threePics[1].color && threePics[0].color === threePics[2].color) {

                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Same shape and color pays " + (SAME_BOTH * betAmount) + " on a bet of " + betAmount;
                    credit = credit + (SAME_SHAPE * betAmount);

                } 
            else if (threePics[0].shape === threePics[1].shape && threePics[0].shape === threePics[2].shape) {

                      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Same shape pays " + (SAME_SHAPE * betAmount) + " on a bet of " + betAmount;
                    credit = credit + (SAME_SHAPE * betAmount);

                } else if (threePics[0].color === threePics[1].color && threePics[0].color === threePics[2].color) {

                     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Same color pays " + (SAME_COLOR * betAmount) + " on a bet of " + betAmount;
                    credit = credit + (SAME_COLOR * betAmount);
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Too bad. Loss of " + betAmount;
                }



        }
    }
```

Comment: You can adjust the width and height, but if you want to prevent to do lots of calculations, you probably should just resize them

Comment: Resizing them in the browser is often a bad idea as the device must still pull down the full-size image then go through the work of resizing.  For large images pulled down over a mobile connection that can be wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the width and height

```
document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).width = '12px';
document.getElementById("img" + (i+1)).height = '12px';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Illustrator to create the images, one option would be to create them as svg and embed them inside the `<svg>` tag and set the properties there. Also simple css trick to hardcode the height*width and preferably use '%' for responsive layout.